# What's the output impedance of this circuit?

Tags: impedance

The following is a question from 8.18 in  *[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf)*, page 342.

Consider the circuit in this following figure. \$(\frac{W} {L})_{1-4} =\frac{50} {0.5} \$, \$|{I_D}_{1-4}| = 0.5\ \mathrm{mA}\$, \$R_2 = 3\ \mathrm{k\Omega}\$.

[image]

[image]

$$R_{out} = \frac{V_t} {I_t} = r_{o4} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \parallel r_{o2}$$

Is there anything wrong? Am I correct?

$$R_{out} = \frac{r_{o4} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \parallel r_{o2}} { 1 + A \beta}$$

Which one is the correct?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be correct but generally, in a circuit like this we might choose R1+R2 to dominate and keep the open-loop gain more defined.

Comment: If you want to determine the output impedance of this circuit, you have to resort to an equivalent small-signal (linear) circuit and calculate \$r_{out}\$. If you want to simulate with SPICE, as it is a non-linear circuit, use a .TF statement like .TF V(1) IT in which V(1) is the output voltage at which you've installed a 1-A current source IT.

Comment: @Andyaka There are two versions. Can you take a look?

Comment: @VerbalKint There are two versions of \$R_{out}\$? which one is the correct?

Comment: No idea but if you want to simulate in SPICE that circuit and check your answer, you cannot avoid biasing your network properly, e.g. restore the dc source \$V_b\$, \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{DD}\$ to obtain a meaningful output voltage. Then you can measure \$r_{out}\$ in these conditions. If you don't want to implement a .TF statement, then measure \$V_{out1}\$ for \$I_{out1}\$ then change the absorbed current a bit and measure \$V_{out2}\$ for \$I_{out2}\$. Compute \$r_{out}\$ as \$\Delta\$V over \$\Delta\$I.

Comment: You've added the 2nd one since I commented. Meaning my comment applies to your pre-edited question. However, as an observation I would say that both your circuits are different so, what can you expect from a proper answer?

Comment: For the circuit with a negative feedback (voltage type feedback). This one will be correct Rout = R_open_loop/(1 + Aol * Beta). Where R_open loop = ro4||ro2||(R1 + R2)

Comment: @G36 Nice , thank you for clarifying things here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method for calculating the output impedance of a circuit with negative feedback is

a) To open the feedback loop and to find first the output impedance Zo without feedback (the DC operating point and the loading conditions at the output must not change)

b) From system theory we know that the closed-loop output impedance is Zo/(1-LG).
(Note that the loop gain LG must be a negativ value for negative feedback)
This applies for voltage-controlled feedback only (as is the case for the circuit under discussion). For current-controlled feedback the ouput impedance Zo must be multiplied with (1-LG).

Comment: Can you draw a diagram for my circuit on how to calculate this loop gain? I need a concrete example instead of pure theory.